# Cassandra Map Reduce for TimeUUID columns

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra

I recently Setup 4 node Cassandra cluster for learning with one column family which hold time series data as.

Key -> {column name: timeUUID, column value: csv log line, ttl: 1year}, I use Netflix Astyanax java client to load about 1 million log lines.

I also configured Hadoop to run map-reduce jobs with 1 namenode and 4 datanode's to run some analytics on Cassandra data.

All the available examples on internet uses column name as SlicePredicate for Hadoop Job Configuration, where as I have timeUUID as columns how can I efficiently feed Cassandra data to Hadoop Job configurator with batches of 1000 columns at one time.

There are more than 10000 column's for some rows in this test data and expected to be more in real data.

---

## I configure my job as

```
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(getConf(), JOB_NAME);
Job.setJarByClass(LogTypeCounterByDate.class);
job.setMapperClass(LogTypeCounterByDateMapper.class);       
job.setReducerClass(LogTypeCounterByDateReducer.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

ConfigHelper.setRangeBatchSize(getConf(), 1000);


SliceRange sliceRange = new SliceRange(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]), 
    ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]), true, 1000);

SlicePredicate slicePredicate = new SlicePredicate();
slicePredicate.setSlice_range(sliceRange);


ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, COLUMN_FAMILY);
ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), INPUT_RPC_PORT);
ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), INPUT_INITIAL_ADRESS);
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), INPUT_PARTITIONER);
ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(job.getConfiguration(), slicePredicate);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(OUTPUT_PATH));
job.waitForCompletion(true);
return job.isSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

But I can't able to understand how I define Mapper, kindly can you provide template for Mapper class.

```
public static class LogTypeCounterByDateMapper extends Mapper<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>, Text, LongWritable>
{
    private Text key = null;
    private LongWritable value = null;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context){

    }

    public void map(ByteBuffer key, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn> columns, Context context){
        //String[] lines = columns.;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone kindly reply to my query, got struck with this from last 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConfigHelper.setRangeBatchSize(getConf(), 1000)
...
SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setSlice_range(new SliceRange(TimeUUID.asByteBuffer(startValue), TimeUUID.asByteBuffer(endValue), false, 1000))
ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(conf, predicate)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, sorry for delay in replying. Will the SlicePredicate limits number of columns fetched to 1000 or it will fetch all the columns with batch size of 1000?

Comment: `ConfigHelper.setRangeBatchSize(getConf(), 1000)` sets the batch size, while the `SlicePredicate` limits the column count.

Comment: I want to read all the columns for a every key in the column family but the SlicePredicate limit returns only 1000 records in above example for each row, but there are more columns than that limit. I understand from document that if I set the limit to high value then Thrift will bring the whole results in memory before returning to client. Actually I want to get 1000 column values in each batch for same row key.

Comment: How many columns do you typically have?  Are you actually running into memory issues?

Comment: I'm expecting columns in 100000-500000 range over a period of 1 year, no currently I'm not hitting memory limits as sample data limits to max 1000 columns for a row.

Comment: My advice is to shard your data, possibly using composite keys (either manually created or using the composite feature).  You don't want a model where you have unbounded row growth.  There are lots of ways to do this using known "sentinel" values like dates or other values you can easily determine at query time.  This will address your concern about serializing everything in a row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was also feeling the same and trying to identify if there are ways to do if in future there are timeouts or memory exceptions even with keys like "key_month". Thanks once again for your valuable help through out this post.

Comment: A common sentinel key I've used is a "daystamp", which is the unix epoch at the start of the day.  You can do multi-get queries with lots of daystamps passed in a single query, thus allowing your shards to be small without sacrificing the ability to query across a large range.